# Conventions in wiki.ros

Tags: ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For example in: http://wiki.ros.org/stdr_simulator/Tutorials/Create%20a%20map%20with%20gmapping there are several sections numbered 0.1

Is the idea that they are strict independent alternatives to each other? It's not totally clear, and sometimes it seems like there's a dependency between identically numbered sections.

Or is that a typo?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/280981/conventions-in-wiki.ros.../) by [pitosalas](https://answers.ros.org/users/30692/pitosalas/) on ROS Answers with karma: 628 on 2018-01-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That was using level 3 headings instead of level 2 headings so they didn't enumerate properly. I've fixed it and they're enumerated correctly now.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2018-01-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1